# How to unzip GZ files using Power Query?

Tags: excel, gzip, powerquery, data-analysis, m

For zip files, I found this [code](https://sql10.blogspot.com/2016/06/reading-zip-files-in-powerquery-m.html) and this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OzQ44gwi5Kw) that explain how to use the code and it works well.

The problem is that I have `gz` files and not `zip` files. The `gz` file contains a `csv`.

So I tried udapting some values like using [Compression.GZip](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/compression-type) instead of Compression.Deflate but that didn't help. I'm still getting an empty table.

```vb
(GZFile) =>
let
    Header = BinaryFormat.Record([
        MiscHeader = BinaryFormat.Binary(14),
        BinarySize = BinaryFormat.ByteOrder(BinaryFormat.UnsignedInteger32, ByteOrder.LittleEndian),
        FileSize   = BinaryFormat.ByteOrder(BinaryFormat.UnsignedInteger32, ByteOrder.LittleEndian),
        FileNameLen= BinaryFormat.ByteOrder(BinaryFormat.UnsignedInteger16, ByteOrder.LittleEndian),
        ExtrasLen  = BinaryFormat.ByteOrder(BinaryFormat.UnsignedInteger16, ByteOrder.LittleEndian)    
    ]),
 
    HeaderChoice = BinaryFormat.Choice(
        BinaryFormat.ByteOrder(BinaryFormat.UnsignedInteger32, ByteOrder.LittleEndian),
        each if _ <> 67324752             // not the IsValid number? then return a dummy formatter
            then BinaryFormat.Record([IsValid = false, Filename=null, Content=null])
            else BinaryFormat.Choice(
                    BinaryFormat.Binary(26),      // Header payload - 14+4+4+2+2
                    each BinaryFormat.Record([
                        IsValid  = true,
                        Filename = BinaryFormat.Text(Header(_)[FileNameLen]),
                        Extras   = BinaryFormat.Text(Header(_)[ExtrasLen]),
                        Content  = BinaryFormat.Transform(
                            BinaryFormat.Binary(Header(_)[BinarySize]),
                            // (x) => try Binary.Buffer(Binary.Decompress(x, Compression.Deflate)) otherwise null
                            (x) => try Binary.Buffer(Binary.Decompress(x, Compression.GZip)) otherwise null
                        )
                        ]),
                        type binary                   // enable streaming
                )
    ),
 
    ZipFormat = BinaryFormat.List(HeaderChoice, each _[IsValid] = true),
 
    Entries = List.Transform(
        List.RemoveLastN( ZipFormat(GZFile), 1),
        (e) => [FileName = e[Filename], Content = e[Content] ]
    )
in
    Table.FromRecords(Entries)
```

Can you guys show me how to modify the code please ?

Comment: What is inside the gzip?

Comment: It contains a single `csv` file

Comment: You're in luck then. I'll provide an answer.

Comment: Thank you my friend. I also have this same `gz` file in a sharepoint if reading it from there will be easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read a CSV in GZIP as follows:

```
let
    Source = Binary.Decompress(File.Contents("C:\Users\Dav\Downloads\test.gz"), Compression.GZip),
    #"Imported CSV" = Csv.Document(Source,[Delimiter=",", Encoding=1252])

in
    #"Imported CSV"
```

You can also read more on Chris Webb's [blog](https://blog.crossjoin.co.uk/2015/12/08/working-with-compression-in-power-query-and-power-bi-desktop/).